# -[RCTRootView cancelTouches]` is deprecated and will be deleted soon in react native map

Tags: ios, react-native

I am using react-native-map and it works well on ios and android.

my react native version is 0.61.2.
But in ios, when I click map, then shows warning "-[RCTRootView cancelTouches]` is deprecated and will be deleted soon.".

What is this and how to remove this warning?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

See [this commit](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/commit/36307d87e1974aff1abac598da2fd11c4e8e23c1) which is now in react-native 0.61+

Although it says deprecated, according to [the conversation in this pull request](https://github.com/kmagiera/react-native-gesture-handler/pull/657) it will be added back to react-native core.

You can dismiss it till the react-native team removes the warning:

`` console.ignoredYellowBox = ['Warning: `-[RCTRootView cancelTouches]`']; ``

Or you downgrade react-native to a version below 0.61.

Some libraries like [react-native-gesture-handler](https://github.com/kmagiera/react-native-gesture-handler) still call the cancelTouches method. Thats why u see this warning.

I was using react-native-gesture-handler which gave this warning on debug mode and caused crashes in release builds on both android and ios. Fixed the crashes by adding `import 'react-native-gesture-handler'` at the top level of index.js.

Comment: I tried adding `import "react-native-gesture-handler"` to index.js and/or app.js, it didn't work. I also tried using YellowBox to ignore warnings at the component level, app.js level, and index.js level, the warning Is still showing

Comment: Could you please point out the exact piece of [the conversation in this pull request](https://github.com/kmagiera/react-native-gesture-handler/pull/657) where one can assume it will be added back to react-native core?

Comment: @MikeMajara https://github.com/kmagiera/react-native-gesture-handler/pull/657#issuecomment-534907082

Comment: Where in the conversation does it say it will be added back?

Comment: Using `console.ignoredYellowBox = ['Warning: `-[RCTRootView cancelTouches]`'];` to ignore the yellow boxes did not work for me. However this did: `import {YellowBox} from 'react-native';
YellowBox.ignoreWarnings(['`-[RCTRootView cancelTouches]`']);`

Answer (score 8):

Muhammed's answer is mostly correct, however in order to stop crashes you also need to wrap the App in the React Native Gesture Handler HOC as follows:

*index.js*

```
import 'react-native-gesture-handler'
import { gestureHandlerRootHOC } from 'react-native-gesture-handler';
```

*index.js*

```
AppRegistry.registerComponent(appName, () => gestureHandlerRootHOC(App));
```

Note You must have these imports as the very first imports for the fix to work.

This is true for React Native 61.2 and react-native-gesture-handler 1.4.1

Note: The official React Native docs suggest using the `YellowBox` module to ignore the warnings as. For example:

```
import {YellowBox} from 'react-native';

YellowBox.ignoreWarnings(['`-[RCTRootView cancelTouches]`']);
```

Comment: the higher order component is only necessary for Android. iOS only apps can ignore

Answer (score 0):

console.ignoredYellowBox = true
will remove all warnings

Answer (score -1):

This was happening while using `react-native-video` (whenever I clicked inside a video that was playing). I upgraded `react-native-gesture-handler` to version 1.5.2 and the warning went away.

Comment: the warning still present in 1.5.3